# Reversing of tuple containing more than 2 elements

Tags: python, list, indexing, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a tuple in different ways. Can i change the order in way (bond,james,number). I know how to change it if there are only 2 elements in tuple but how to do it when I have 3 and more? I got (number,bond,james) but how to do it in different ways, not just reversing. My code:

```
def change(lst):
    list2 = [t[::-1] for t in lst]
    list2.reverse()
    return list2

print(change([("James", "Bond", "300184"),("Harry", "Prince", "111000")]))
```

Comment: Adding expected output could help.

Comment: IIUC, do you only want to reverse the first two elements in a tuple and leave the rest of the elements as is?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reverse the first two elements we can leverage on [tuple unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in for loop.

```
lst = [("James", "Bond", "300184"),("Harry", "Prince", "111000")]
out = [(sec, fir, *rem) for fir, sec, *rem in lst]
print(out)
# [('Bond', 'James', '300184'), ('Prince', 'Harry', '111000')]
```

This solution would reverse each tuple in list as below:

```
(a, b, c...z) --> (b, a, c...z)
```

- `c...z` can be 0 or more elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all possible combinations of a tuple using itertools permutation:

```
from itertools import permutations
list1 = [("James", "Bond", "300184"), ("Harry", "Prince", "111000")]

for tup in list1:
    possible_permutations = permutations(tup)
    print(tuple(possible_permutations))
```

Output:

```
(('James', 'Bond', '300184'), ('James', '300184', 'Bond'), ('Bond', 'James', '300184'), ('Bond', '300184', 'James'), ('300184', 'James', 'Bond'), ('300184', 'Bond', 'James'))
(('Harry', 'Prince', '111000'), ('Harry', '111000', 'Prince'), ('Prince', 'Harry', '111000'), ('Prince', '111000', 'Harry'), ('111000', 'Harry', 'Prince'), ('111000', 'Prince', 'Harry'))
```